# Wrong behavior for kendo-colorpicker angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, color-picker, kendo-colorpicker

I have a problem in the display when using the kendo-colorpicker with Angular. I am using Angular 8 and "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.0.0":

[image: Picture of the problem]

Even when I upgrade the kendo-angular-inputs to 6.4.0 I still see the same problem.

Comment: Please be specific about the exact nature of the problem (not just a screenshot) and post your code. As it stands this question is essentially unanswerable